# Count number of occurrences of distinct values

Tags: mysql, loops, csv, count

I have several csv files and the below code is used to count the number of occurrences of distinct values in a table loaded with the first csv file. All csv files have only one column named "numbers".

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'path/to/file.csv' 
INTO TABLE table_1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

SELECT numbers, COUNT(1) as count 
FROM table_1 
GROUP BY numbers 
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 10
INTO OUTFILE 'path/to/file_with_results_1.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I need to rewrite this code in order to update the result reached in the first csv file with the values in the other csv files.

In the end, the process will be:

1) load a table with the first csv file;

2) count the number of occurrences of distinct values and save a csv file with the 10 most frequent numbers;

3) load a new table with the second csv file;

4) recount the number of occurrences of distinct values and save a new csv file with the 10 most frequent numbers;

5) repeat this process up to the last csv file.

In order to make this process faster, I would like to avoid having to start the counting process with the first file everytime a new csv file is loaded. For example: when the last csv file is loaded, it will take a long time to count all the data, beginning in the first file.

It will be faster if the counting process is resumed from where it stopped.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you need to "start the counting process with the first file everytime a new csv file is loaded"? If you didn't use a new table each time than you would only have to load each file once?

Comment: When the first csv file (with 10.000 rows) is loaded, the counting proccess will use these 10.000 numbers. When the second csv file is loaded, with 26.000 rows, the table will have 36.000 rows and the counting proccess will use these 36.000 numbers. So, each time a csv file is loaded, the number of rows in the table is increased and the counting process will analyse all the rows that exist in the table, from the first line (that was loaded from the first csv file). I am trying to find a way so that the counting process does not always start from the first row (first csv file),

Comment: Select counts without limiting for each separate table. Then load all of sums files, summarise, limit and save.

Comment: I'm starting to not understand your requirement. If you don't want file1's numbers to be included when you do the counts for file2, then you can TRUNCATE the table you loaded file1 into (quickly delete all the rows). If you DO want the numbers from file1 to count towards the output for file2 then DON'T delete them out of the table. Use the same table all the time, but DO/DON'T delete from it according to what you want in the output. Each file will only be read once regardless

Comment: Caius, the counting proccess will analyse all the rows in the table. When the first csv file is loaded, the table will have 10.000 rows. The second csv file will increase the table to 36.000 rows. I am trying to write a code that takes the result of the 10.000 rows and adds the result for 26.000 rows. It will be faster to analyse 26.000 rows instead of 36.000 rows.